# PostgreSQL | La edición manual en cliente PostgreSQL no se queda guardado

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin

Cuando edito un número directamente en postgreSQL utilizando el cliente PGAdmin4, se ve el número cambiado, pero si vuelvo a mostrar los datos de la base de datos, no se ha guardado la edición que he hecho:
¿Cómo se guarda la edición desde programa cliente?

Un saludo.

Ejemplo:

Veo un 4...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Manualmente lo cambio a 101...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago un view all rows de nuevo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¡El 101 no se ha guardado, ha vuelto al 4 anterior!**

Comment: ¿Estás _commiteando_ los cambios?

Comment: Desde Pgadmin4 de commitea? (Crei que tenía que haber mencionado que utilizo PGAdmin4). Disculpad.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado:
El cuarto botón "Save data changes(F6)" sirve para guardar los cambios que hemos hecho.
Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]